# Syntax error python infile

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to get this program to open the file and print a list of whether its a CD or a DVD and the amount they owe and the customers name, but I get a syntax error with printing the customers name

this is the syntax error I'm getting -

> invalid syntax: BWHW7.pyw, line 25, pos 37 in file c:\Users\Benjaguin\Desktop\python\BWHW7.pyw, line 25
>       print(customer_name, end='\t')

This is code i used..

```
 CD_SPINDLE = 16.50
    DVD_SPINDLE = 21.75

    def main():
       cd_spindle_counter = 0
       dvd_spindle_counter = 0

        print("Guest Name \tSpindle Code\tAmount of Spindles\tAmount Due")
       print()

       try:
           infile = open('spindles.txt', 'r')

           customer_name = infile.readline()

           while customer_name != '':
               customer_name = customer_name.rstrip('\n')
               print(customer_name, end='\t')

               spindle_code = infile.readline()
               spindle_code = room_type.rstrip('\n')
               print(spindle_code, end='\t')

               spindle_amount = infile.readline()
               spindle_amount = int(spindle_amount)
               print(spindle_amount, end='\t')

               if spindle_code == "c" or spindle_Code == "C":
                   payment_due = spindle_amount * CD_SPINDLE
                   cd_spindle_counter += 1
               elif spindle_code == "d" or spinlde_code == "D":
                   payment_due = spindle_amount * DVD_SPINDLE
                   dvd_spindle_counter += 1
               else:
                   payment_due = 0

               total_spindle_payment += payment_due

               if payment_due ==0:
                   print('invalid code')
               else:
                 print('$', format(payment_due, '8,.2f'))

               guest_name = infile.readline()

           infile.close()

           print()
           print('total number of CD spindles sold:   ', cd_spindle_counter)
           print('total number of DVD spindles sold:    ',dvd_spindle_counter)
           print()
           print('total CD/DVD purchases:   ', end='')
           print('$', format(total_spindle_payment, ',.2f'), sep='')

       except IOError:
           print('an error occured trying to open or read spindle.txt')

    main()
```

Comment: Are you running python 2 or 3 ? end argument for print should be only supported in python 3

Comment: Your indentation, though legal, is not very consistent. Besides, you should not tag Python2 **and** Python3, because each of those tag is aimed at version-specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was due to inconsistent indentation. I've corrected that (used an indentation of `2` consistently), and now it's working:

```
CD_SPINDLE = 16.50
DVD_SPINDLE = 21.75

def main():
  cd_spindle_counter = 0
  dvd_spindle_counter = 0

  print("Guest Name \tSpindle Code\tAmount of Spindles\tAmount Due")
  print()
  try:
    infile = open('spindles.txt', 'r')

    customer_name = infile.readline()

    while customer_name != '':
      customer_name = customer_name.rstrip('\n')
      print(customer_name, end='\t')

      spindle_code = infile.readline()
      spindle_code = room_type.rstrip('\n')
      print(spindle_code, end='\t')

      spindle_amount = infile.readline()
      spindle_amount = int(spindle_amount)
      print(spindle_amount, end='\t')

      if spindle_code == "c" or spindle_Code == "C":
        payment_due = spindle_amount * CD_SPINDLE
        cd_spindle_counter += 1
      elif spindle_code == "d" or spinlde_code == "D":
        payment_due = spindle_amount * DVD_SPINDLE
        dvd_spindle_counter += 1
      else:
        payment_due = 0

      total_spindle_payment += payment_due

      if payment_due ==0:
        print('invalid code')
      else:
        print('$', format(payment_due, '8,.2f'))

      guest_name = infile.readline()

    infile.close()

    print()
    print('total number of CD spindles sold:   ', cd_spindle_counter)
    print('total number of DVD spindles sold:    ',dvd_spindle_counter)
    print()
    print('total CD/DVD purchases:   ', end='')
    print('$', format(total_spindle_payment, ',.2f'), sep='')

  except IOError:
    print('an error occured trying to open or read spindle.txt')

main()
```

Comment: I fixed some minor spelling mistakes and indentation but now I'm getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' 

in regards to this part 


spindle_amount = infile.readline()
            spindle_amount = int(spindle_amount)
            print(format(spindle_amount, '3.0f'),'\t')

i tried making it a float but it doenst work either

Comment: In that case you need to show me the text file you're taking inputs from.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the file in text ?

Comment: yeah, sorry  Rex Carr
C
10
Mark Downs
D
3
Wayne Storm
E
9

Comment: Is this all in one line ?